# problem with argument of mq_open() function in C programming

Tags: c, queue, posix, ipc

I was trying the queue functions in `C` successfully.
But now I want to use it for another project, my amazing problem is the name of argument of `mq_open()`.

when I define It to : "`/sp-example-server`" it works
but if I change this name it doesnt work `: : Invalid argument`

```
#define SERVER_HUM   "/foobar"
#define QUEUE_PERMISSIONS 0660
#define MAX_MESSAGES 20
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE 30

struct mq_attr attr;
attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES;
attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_MSG_SIZE;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

if ((hum_q = mq_open (SERVER_HUM , O_CREAT |  O_RDWR , QUEUE_PERMISSIONS , &attr )) == -1)
{
    error("couldnt create queue for humidity\n");
}
```

Comment: [mq_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) explain from where this error can come. May be first try with `attr` set to `NULL`?

Comment: yes, by deletting the `attr` its working, but why ? why it isnt reliable and what is my exactly broblem!?